# Biblatex style=authoryear changes

Tags: biblatex

My bibliography is not perfect. I need to make some changes.

**NOW:**

> MUSTERMANN, Hans (1994). The World Wide Web. URL: http:\\websiteisdown.tld\WoWiWe (besucht am 01.02.2013)

**Better:**

> MUSTERMANN, Hans (1994): The World Wide Web. Online http:\\websiteisdown.tld\WoWiWe, Urldate is 02.2013.

The minimal example:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % lang new german

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literaturdatenbank}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    references = {Q}
}
% Names
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literaturdatenbank.bib}
@online{ art:web,
  author = {Hans Mustermann},
  title = {The World Wide Web},
  year = {1994},
  url = {http:\\websiteisdown.tld\WoWiWe},
  urldate = {2013-02-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}  

\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}






\section{Example}
Content
\footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The only differences I am seeing are related to language strings. Is this correct?

Comment: Add `urlseen = {Urldate is},` to the `biblatex` strings you define to get that string. I thought that `url` or `urlfrom` would change the 'URL' bit but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Thanky for answers.

@MarcoDaniel: The german languag is correct.

@cfr: The `urlseen = {Urldate is}` make it better. How can I remove the brackets?

Comment: Use `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}`

Comment: '\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}' remove the brackets.

Comment: I add `url = {Online }` to the biblatex strings.
But now there is a Space between the URL and the , Urldate.
`… urlend , Urladet …`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is the result you're looking for.

[image]

To achieve it, add the following strings to `ngerman`:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    references = {Q},
    urlseen = {Urldate is},
    url = {Online}
}
```

Also, redefine the `url` and `urldate` as follows:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
```

and add the line

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % lang new german

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literaturdatenbank}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    references = {Q},
    urlseen = {Urldate is},
    url = {Online}
}
% Names
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literaturdatenbank.bib}
@online{ art:web,
  author = {Hans Mustermann},
  title = {The World Wide Web},
  year = {1994},
  url = {http:\\websiteisdown.tld\WoWiWe},
  urldate = {2013-02-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Example}
Content
\footcite[Vgl.][]{art:web}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Some variants**

With

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\textsc{\bibstring{url}}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
```

you get

[image]

while with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{\bibstring{url}}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: you forgot the colon between the name and the title. I think one may add to the preamble: `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}`if it is wanted for all types of entry. Or just xpatch `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}`.

Comment: @Bernard There's no colon in the OP's example.

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding the other. I was speaking of the `Better`  example: MUSTERMANN, Hans (1994)`:` The World Wide Web.

Comment: @Bernard Oh, sorry, you're right. I thought after "Online"...

Comment: I change this to remove the dot: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addperiod}` to`\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1},}.
`

Comment: @user5361 The right way is `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}\addcomma}`. I've added in the answer.